# css. Вопрос про позиционирование, или нет?

Tags: css

Очень долго искал, но не нашел ответ.

Можно ли как-либо абсолютно позиционированному  элементу позиционироваться относительно `body`, если этот элемент имеет одного или несколько абсолютно позиционированных предков?

[image: скрин]

Проблема в том, что содержимое подпапок начиная с содержимого папки 3.1 (на скрине) не растягиваются на всю длину контента а только в пределах родителя.

вот так надо (сделано на скорую в фоторедакторе(ой ошибся с очередностью папок но суть не в этом)):
[image: как надо]
кстати `body` простирается дальше вправо,просто так заскринил

Дерево папок на чекбоксах и по-другому сделать средствами `css`, `html` я не вижу как (ховеры присутствуют,но мне нужно чтобы была возможность закрепить отображения контента папок).

Есть 4 варианта решения как подсказали:

- margin-right:-35px;
- min-width: 75%;
- white-space: nowrap;
- right:10px;

К сожалению все эти способа не дают приемлемого результата. При уменьшении окна браузера не стягивается\съёживается контент адекватно. Да и выглядят тоже так себе.

### Неужели это лучшее, что можно выжать в такой ситуации? может можно сделать тоже самое по-другому,не на чекбоксах  или еще как? эх..

Код громоздок, не знаю стоит ли скидывать, и куда... `jsfiddle`?

```css
body {
  background-color: #2e3436;
  font-size: 100%;
}
b::selection,
a::selection,
img::selection {
  background-color: rgba(153, 204, 255, 0.5);
}
b {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
img {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
li:hover img {
  background-color: white;
  border: 3px solid white;
}
a:active {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/*---огибание текста ссылок фавиконок---*/

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 25px;
  padding: 2px 0;
}
li img {
  /*чтобы ссылки правильно
  огибали фавиконы*/
  position: absolute;
}
/*...........*/

a {
  color: #ccc;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
ul li:hover {
  /*ul- чтобы побороть специфичность селектора*/
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.2);
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.2);
}
/*------ новые точки списка ------*/

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 15px;
  bord er: 1px solid red;
}
li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  left: 0;
  width: 9px;
  min-height: 9px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  border-radius: 50% 14px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
li:hover:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(225, 225, 220, 0.85);
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
/*---чередующяяся подсветка списка---*/

li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgba(225, 225, 220, 0.08);
}
/*--------/// side-list ///-----------*/

label {
  transition: 0.4s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
.folder b {
  font-size: 90%;
}
.folder_c li {
  width: auto;
  cursor: default;
}
.folder1 {
  border-radius: 0 14px 0 0;
}
/*-----точечки папок----*/

label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  width: 9px;
  min-height: 9px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  vertical-align: center;
}
input:checked +label:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(225, 225, 220, 0.85);
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
/*---------*/

.side-list {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  min-height: 150px;
  border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
  margin-left: 13px;
}
/*/////////////////////////*/

.folder {
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.folder_c {
  /*folder content*/
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(46, 49, 50, 0.9);
  padding: 8px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
  position: absolute;
  left: 160px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.55);
  padding-top: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  /*из-за кастомных точечек списков фона*/
}
/*...........*/

.folder:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.folder:hover> b {
  color: #2e3436;
}
label {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: auto;
}
input:checked + label {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #2e3436;
}
/*...........*/

.folder {
  /*для лейбла чтоб выглядил как блок*/
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
.pre-folder:hover >.folder_c {
  display: block;
}
input:checked +label+ div {
  /* не удалять*/
  display: block;
}
input
/*:not(checked)*/

{
  /* скрывает чекбокс*/
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
/*-----------*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Bookmarks</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="side-list">
    <input type="checkbox" id="folder1" />
    <label class="folder folder1" for="folder1">
      <b>Folder 1</b>
      <div class="folder_c">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <img width="16" src="index_files/favicon (1).ico">
            <a href="https://www.amazon.com/Monoprice-Charge-Transfer-Protection-Switch/dp/B00Y42IE76/">Amazon.com: Monoprice USB 2.0 to Micro B Sync &amp; Fast Charge Cable with Data Transfer Protection On/Off Switch - 30/20 AWG 4.5ft (1): Computers &amp; Accessories</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img width="16" src="index_files/favicon (2).ico">
            <a href="http://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-Male-to-Female-Charging-Switch-Data-Cable-for-Samsung-Galaxy-Tab-P7500-P7510-/271524739619?">USB Male to Female Charging Switch Data Cable for Samsung Galaxy Tab P7500 P7510 | eBay</a>
          </li>
          <li title="base64 иконка">
            <img width="16" src="">
            <a href="https://www.qwant.com/web"> Веб-сайт Qwant</a>
          </li>
          <li title="локальная иконка">
            <img width="16" src="index_files/favicon.ico">
            <a href="https://www.gigablast.com/">Gigablast - An Alternative Open Source Search Engine</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://search.disconnect.me/">Disconnect Search: Search privately using your favorite search engine</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="folder2" />
    <label class="folder" for="folder2">
      <b>FOLDER 2</b>
      <div class="folder_c">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <img width="16" src="index_files/favicon (1).ico">
            <a href="https://www.amazon.com/Monoprice-Charge-Transfer-Protection-Switch/dp/B00Y42IE76/">Amazon.com...</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img width="16" src="index_files/favicon (2).ico">
            <a href="http://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-Male-to-Female-Charging-Switch-Data-Cable-for-Samsung-Galaxy-Tab-P7500-P7510-/271524739619?">USB Male to Female...</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </label>
    <!-- ПАПКИ ВСТАВЛЯТЬ ТУТ -->
    <!-- ТЕСТ -->
    <div class="pre-folder">
      <input type="checkbox" id="folder3" />
      <label class="folder" for="folder3">
        <b>FOLDER 3</b>
      </label>
      <div class="folder_c">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <img width="16" src="index_files/favicon (1).ico">
            <a href="https://www.amazon.com/Monoprice-Charge-Transfer-Protection-Switch/dp/B00Y42IE76/">Amazon.comrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
      rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
      rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
      rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr...</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img width="16" src="index_files/favicon (2).ico">
            <a href="http://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-Male-to-Female-Charging-Switch-Data-Cable-for-Samsung-Galaxy-Tab-P7500-P7510-/271524739619?">USB Male to Female...</a>
          </li>
          <!--2-->
          <div class="rel">
            <div class="pre-folder">
              <input type="checkbox" id="folder4" />
              <label class="folder" for="folder4">
                <b>FOLDER 3.1</b>
              </label>
              <div class="folder_c">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <img width="16" src="index_files/favicon (1).ico">
                    <a href="https://www.amazon.com/Monoprice-Charge-Transfer-Protection-Switch/dp/B00Y42IE76/">Amazon.comrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
         rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
         rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
         rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</a>
                  </li>

                  <!--3-->
                  <div class="pre-folder">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="folder5" />
                    <label class="folder" for="folder5">
                      <b>FOLDER 3.2</b>
                    </label>
                    <div class="folder_c">
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <img width="16" src="index_files/favicon (1).ico">
                          <a href="https://www.amazon.com/Monoprice-Charge-Transfer-Protection-Switch/dp/B00Y42IE76/">Amazon.comrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
            rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
            rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
            rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <img width="16" src="index_files/favicon (2).ico">
                          <a href="http://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-Male-to-Female-Charging-Switch-Data-Cable-for-Samsung-Galaxy-Tab-P7500-P7510-/271524739619?">USB Male to Female...</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!--3-->

                  <li>
                    <img width="16" src="index_files/favicon (2).ico">
                    <a href="http://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-Male-to-Female-Charging-Switch-Data-Cable-for-Samsung-Galaxy-Tab-P7500-P7510-/271524739619?">USB Male to Female...</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--/2-->
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ТЕСТ -->
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Код лучше сюда.

Comment: p.s. код 10 раз переделывал все еще будучи новичком по этому  такой мутный.

Comment: p.p.s. первые 2 папки не работают, я пока ими не занимался.

Comment: Каким образом задаётся размер абсолютных папок? margin-ами? Пробовали уже убирать правый маргин? И вообще, зачем им абсолютное позиционирование, разве относительное не работает?

Comment: задаются размеры так:
max-width:1200px;
left:160px;
margin-top:-25px;
margin-right:8px;

по всякому пробовал маргины тут не причем .
относительное? всмысле relative? не понял

Comment: а если `.folder-c` поставить не `max-width: 1200px`, а `min-width: 75%` или даже 100%, но со 100%-ми точно за экран вылезать будет

Comment: Нужно сделать так, чтобы текст не разбивался на несколько строк. whit-space: nowrap Тогда папка будет растягиваться по длине строки

Comment: А вместо того, чтобы фоткать, надо просто просмотреть сайт инструментами разработчика, которые есть во всех главных браузерах

Comment: stackanon,  Sergey спасибо, оба способа работают, правда к сожалению при уменьшении окна браузера не стягивается\съёживается  контент адекватно.

Comment: но неужто нет решения по элегантнее? кроме как переосмыслить и переписать весь код..) идей как сделать по-другому к сожалению нет

Comment: Может единицы vh и vw пригодятся,

Answer (score 1):

Эту задачу можно решить так: сделать все абсолютные блоки шириной до конца экрана, а внутрь добавить блок на ширину контента (например, inline-block). Я отредактировал ваш пример, html остался прежним, а в стилях обратите внимание на разделы: `.folder_c` и `.folder_c>ul`. По сути, я перенес из первого блока все оформление во внутренний UL.

В результате, окна показываются на всю свою ширину, но когда упираются в правый край экрана (или body, как вам угодно), то начинают сжиматься.

Надеюсь, это то что вам было нужно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
  background-color: #2e3436;
  font-size: 100%;
}

b::selection,
a::selection,
img::selection {
  background-color: rgba(153, 204, 255, 0.5);
}

b {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

img {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

li:hover img {
  background-color: white;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

a:active {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/*---огибание текста ссылок фавиконок---*/

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 25px;
  padding: 2px 0;
}

li img {
  /*чтобы ссылки правильно
        огибали фавиконы*/
  position: absolute;
}


/*...........*/

a {
  color: #ccc;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

ul li:hover {
  /*ul- чтобы побороть специфичность селектора*/
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.2);
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.2);
}


/*------ новые точки списка ------*/

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 15px;
  bord er: 1px solid red;
}

li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  left: 0;
  width: 9px;
  min-height: 9px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  border-radius: 50% 14px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

li:hover:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(225, 225, 220, 0.85);
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
}


/*---чередующяяся подсветка списка---*/

li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgba(225, 225, 220, 0.08);
}


/*--------/// side-list ///-----------*/

label {
  transition: 0.4s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.folder b {
  font-size: 90%;
}

.folder_c li {
  width: auto;
  cursor: default;
}

.folder1 {
  border-radius: 0 14px 0 0;
}


/*-----точечки папок----*/

label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  width: 9px;
  min-height: 9px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  vertical-align: center;
}

input:checked+label:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(225, 225, 220, 0.85);
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
}


/*---------*/

.side-list {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  min-height: 150px;
  border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
  margin-left: 13px;
}


/*/////////////////////////*/

.folder {
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.folder_c {
  /*folder content*/
  display: none;
  /* background-color: rgba(46, 49, 50, 0.9); */
  /* padding: 8px; */
  /* max-width: 1200px; */
  /* border-radius: 5px; */
  /* box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px rgb(0 0 0 / 50%); */
  position: absolute;
  left: 160px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  /* border: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.55); */
  padding-top: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  /* min-width: max-content; */
  right: 0;
  /*из-за кастомных точечек списков фона*/
}


/*...........*/

.folder_c>ul {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(46, 49, 50, 0.9);
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px rgb(0 0 0 / 50%);
  /* position: absolute; */
  /* left: 160px; */
  /* margin-top: -25px; */
  /* margin-right: 8px; */
  border: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.55);
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.folder:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.folder:hover>b {
  color: #2e3436;
}

label {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: auto;
}

input:checked+label {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #2e3436;
}


/*...........*/

.folder {
  /*для лейбла чтоб выглядил как блок*/
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

.pre-folder:hover>.folder_c {
  display: block;
}

input:checked+label+div {
  /* не удалять*/
  display: block;
}

input
/*:not(checked)*/

{
  /* скрывает чекбокс*/
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}


/*-----------*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Bookmarks</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="side-list">
    <input type="checkbox" id="folder1" />
    <label class="folder folder1" for="folder1">
      <b>Folder 1</b>
      <div class="folder_c">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <img width="16" src="index_files/favicon (1).ico">
            <a href="https://www.amazon.com/Monoprice-Charge-Transfer-Protection-Switch/dp/B00Y42IE76/">Amazon.com: Monoprice USB 2.0 to Micro B Sync &amp; Fast Charge Cable with Data Transfer Protection On/Off Switch - 30/20 AWG 4.5ft (1): Computers &amp; Accessories</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img width="16" src="index_files/favicon (2).ico">
            <a href="http://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-Male-to-Female-Charging-Switch-Data-Cable-for-Samsung-Galaxy-Tab-P7500-P7510-/271524739619?">USB Male to Female Charging Switch Data Cable for Samsung Galaxy Tab P7500 P7510 | eBay</a>
          </li>
          <li title="base64 иконка">
            <img width="16" src="">
            <a href="https://www.qwant.com/web"> Веб-сайт Qwant</a>
          </li>
          <li title="локальная иконка">
            <img width="16" src="index_files/favicon.ico">
            <a href="https://www.gigablast.com/">Gigablast - An Alternative Open Source Search Engine</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://search.disconnect.me/">Disconnect Search: Search privately using your favorite search engine</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="folder2" />
    <label class="folder" for="folder2">
      <b>FOLDER 2</b>
      <div class="folder_c">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <img width="16" src="index_files/favicon (1).ico">
            <a href="https://www.amazon.com/Monoprice-Charge-Transfer-Protection-Switch/dp/B00Y42IE76/">Amazon.com...</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img width="16" src="index_files/favicon (2).ico">
            <a href="http://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-Male-to-Female-Charging-Switch-Data-Cable-for-Samsung-Galaxy-Tab-P7500-P7510-/271524739619?">USB Male to Female...</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </label>
    <!-- ПАПКИ ВСТАВЛЯТЬ ТУТ -->
    <!-- ТЕСТ -->
    <div class="pre-folder">
      <input type="checkbox" id="folder3" />
      <label class="folder" for="folder3">
        <b>FOLDER 3</b>
      </label>
      <div class="folder_c">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <img width="16" src="index_files/favicon (1).ico">
            <a href="https://www.amazon.com/Monoprice-Charge-Transfer-Protection-Switch/dp/B00Y42IE76/">Amazon.comrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
                        rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
                        rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
                        rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr...</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img width="16" src="index_files/favicon (2).ico">
            <a href="http://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-Male-to-Female-Charging-Switch-Data-Cable-for-Samsung-Galaxy-Tab-P7500-P7510-/271524739619?">USB Male to Female...</a>
          </li>
          <!--2-->
          <div class="rel">
            <div class="pre-folder">
              <input type="checkbox" id="folder4" />
              <label class="folder" for="folder4">
                <b>FOLDER 3.1</b>
              </label>
              <div class="folder_c">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <img width="16" src="index_files/favicon (1).ico">
                    <a href="https://www.amazon.com/Monoprice-Charge-Transfer-Protection-Switch/dp/B00Y42IE76/">Amazon.comrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
                                    rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
                                    rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
                                    rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</a>
                  </li>

                  <!--3-->
                  <div class="pre-folder">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="folder5" />
                    <label class="folder" for="folder5">
                      <b>FOLDER 3.2</b>
                    </label>
                    <div class="folder_c">
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <img width="16" src="index_files/favicon (1).ico">
                          <a href="https://www.amazon.com/Monoprice-Charge-Transfer-Protection-Switch/dp/B00Y42IE76/">Amazon.comrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
                                                rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
                                                rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
                                                rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <img width="16" src="index_files/favicon (2).ico">
                          <a href="http://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-Male-to-Female-Charging-Switch-Data-Cable-for-Samsung-Galaxy-Tab-P7500-P7510-/271524739619?">USB Male to Female...</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!--3-->

                  <li>
                    <img width="16" src="index_files/favicon (2).ico">
                    <a href="http://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-Male-to-Female-Charging-Switch-Data-Cable-for-Samsung-Galaxy-Tab-P7500-P7510-/271524739619?">USB Male to Female...</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--/2-->
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ТЕСТ -->
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если у родителя абсолютно позиционированного элемента значение `position` задано как `fixed`, `relative` или `absolute`, то отсчет координат ведется от края родительского элемента.

Comment: вопрос в том, есть ли хитрости чтобы это обойти

Comment: попробуйте включить box-sizing: border-box; для этих элементов, тогда граница будет включаться в их размер

Comment: к сожалению это не то ,сейчас попробую в фоторедакторе показать что я имел ввиду

Comment: @Khipster для fixed  расчёт берётся от body хоть лопни , и ни какой relative не поможет

Comment: приобщил изображение из фоторедактора к вопросу

Comment: @МаксимЛенский если лопнуть с transform, то fixed ведет себя куда более странно, чем кажется, и точно не от body.

Comment: @zb' однако это будет не от relative ... вы согласны ?

Answer (score 0):

Сочетание `position: fixed` и `transform` даёт желаемый эффект
([подробнее о их взаимодействии на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15194313/4928642)):

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 1000px;
  overflow: auto;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

div {
  position: fixed;
  left: 100px;
  right: 100px;
  height: 2em;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, blue, red);
}

div::before {
  content: attr(style);
  color: white;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding-left: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div style="top:50px">
  <div style="top:150px">
    <div style="top:100px">
      <div style="top:800px"></div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```